# How can I update parts of the string that matches some regexp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, string

I have string `"(1,2,3,4,5,6),(1,2,3)"` I would like to change it to `"('1','2','3','4','5','6'),('1','2','3')"` - replase all parts that mathces `/([^,)("])/` with the `'$1', '$2'` etc

Comment: Why not just replace a digit with a digit in apostrophes?

Comment: Because there can be anything not only digits (float numbers, strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"(1,2,3,4,5,6),(1,2,3)".gsub(/([^,)("]\w*)/,"'\\1'")
```

`gsub` is a "global replace" method in [String class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000817). It finds **all** occurrences of given regular expression and replaces them with the string given as the second parameter (as opposed to `sub` which replaces first occurrence only). That string can contain references to groups marked with `()` in the regexp. First group is \1, second is \2, and so on.

Comment: This will work, but you need to add a '+' after the set to get strings, floats, etc. Things might also get tricky with whitespace.

Comment: I made a mistake in regexp it should be ([^,)("]\w*) for more complicate strings. thanks for the answer, could you explain it , please

Comment: I added an explanation and changed the regexp

Comment: @Bohdan Pohorilets Wait, does this pick up "3.3" as an entire "3.3" and not "3" and ".3"?  When I test it, it also breaks up strings with spaces and tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
mystring.gsub(/([\w.]+)/, '\'\1\'')
```

This will replace numbers (ints/floats) and words with their "quote-surrounded" selves while leaving punctuation (except the dot) alone.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED: I think you want to search for this

```
(([^,)("])+)
```

And replace it with this

```
'$1'
```

the looks for anything 1 or more times and assigns it to the $1 variable slot due to using the parenthesis around the "\d".  The replace part will use what it finds as the replacement value.